# Before an attacker attempts to exploit eval(), how would they suspect that it is being used by a target application?

Tags: php, javascript

I am asking the question in the context of <s>XSS</s> RCE/RFI as a result of server-side `eval()` exploitation. It is often recommended to avoid using it, but it is not clear to me how one would attempt to exploit something before figuring out whether it exists or not.

Would an attacker just inject code in every string passed to the server (not just user inputs), and then check whether the app breaks in some way?

Comment: eval() is a core function of JavaScript so attackers can always use it but user input should be always sanitized, encoded and filtered. XSS can be. hecked in many ways. There are reflected, stored, persistent, normal, DOM based and more XSS types.

Comment: @DanielRuf Okay, not arguing. I was trying to determine the likelihood that an attacker will successfully exploit server-side use of eval, even when input is not filtered.

Comment: _Would an attacker just inject code in every string passed to the server (not just user inputs), and then check whether the app breaks in some way?_ Viewing the server logs pretty much says, "Yes". It's easy to hire the use of a VPS and run a scripted attack that blindly bumbles its way through a list of web servers looking for the one that failed "Server Config 101" or the web developer who didn't pay attention to security detail. In fact 4500 requests of that sort over almost a day on a single server was observed over during the day of the Paris Attack, coming from Kuala Lampur. IP block!

Comment: JavaScripts eval() is client-side and runs in every browser with enabled JavaScript support.

Comment: eval() in PHP should never be used, always. If any user input gets into server-side eval, it is not XSS but remote code execution (RCE), RFI or something else. Far worse than XSS which is often not persistent.

Comment: @DanielRuf Yes, but on the client-side it's straightforward to know it is being used. I was more interested in server-side use. Maybe the fault was with my description, sorry. It's not just user input though. One might be using an internal string passed to the server as part of a qualifier. Not sure how plausible it is, but such non-obvious input seems more likely to be overlooked.

Comment: even then the data should be always checked on the server-side and cleaned (striptags, escape, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The attacker does not directly know this but they scan the website with probes for detecting RCE / RFI / LFI vulnerabilities and inject specific code in requests and single GET / POST parameters.

When they know that the result changes depending on the supplied user input they test single parameters with different codes for different attacks.

`eval()` is mostly not needed and should never be used for input which can be manipulated by attackers.

This is also mentioned in the official documentation of PHP, where they warn about the risks.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.phpCaution

> Caution
>
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

As web developer I have never used nor needed `eval()`.

But this is still unrelated to JavaScript, even if there is the `eval()` in JavaScript, but for executing only JavaScript code.

Comment: I amended the description to correct the mistake.